# checking a constructor for NULL?

Tags: c++

I ran across this C++ code:

```
if (Foo f = "something")
{
    ...
}
```

What is the `if` clause checking exactly?  Can a constructor evaluate as NULL?

**EDIT:**

Foo is a class

Comment: Can you give us more context about `Foo` please?

Comment: @erip, I understand that.  But what is the `if` checking?

Comment: Why have you got an assignment in an `if` statement

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I am asking in general.  Why should it matter what Foo is?  It's a class of some sort.  My question is, I don't see how the `if` could possibly be useful.  A constructor can't evaluate to false, right?

Comment: @EdHeal He said he "ran across" the code, implying he didn't write it.

Comment: This can do all sorts of stuff, depending on the actual type `Foo`.

Comment: `=` is an assignment. `==` is a comparison

Comment: @JoelFan I believe it's converting the resultant `Foo` to a boolean expression and evaluating that as the condition of the `if`.

Comment: The result of an assignment is the value of the RHS. It's checking that it isn't falsy, which it never will be unless it's false.

Comment: @ColinBasnett - I take the "ran across" with a pinch of salt

Comment: OK, I like the answer... not sure what all the downvotes and vote to close are all about

Comment: @EdHeal, so I really wrote code that I don't understand and am lying to you all about it?  Is it so implausible that I ran across someone else's code and don't understand it?

Comment: Why is this question unclear? Looks pretty clear to me.

Comment: @JoelFan I think people always get strange question from beginner, they saw your question and through "wtf". This is indeed a strange question but not bad for me.

Comment: @Stargateur, what is strange about it?  I don't understand why there is an "if" surrounding a constructor.  It looks like the programmer expected the constructor to possibly return "false", which makes no sense to me.

Comment: @EdHeal, Olipro, erip: this isn't an assignment at all, this is copy-initialization.

Comment: @Quentin, are you sure it isn't just a straight-up constructor?  I think it is equivalent to `Foo f("something");`

Comment: @JoelFan You right a constructor can't return anything. This is strange like you said because this code don't make any sense. For example, in C that doesn't compile for sure :p. I am quite surprise that it's compile in C++.

Comment: @JoelFan almost. It is equivalent to `Foo f = Foo("something");`, and with copy elision they can be the same (will be the same come C++17).

Comment: @yizzlez I still find the question, as stated, unclear. Does OP not know what `if` does in C++? Do the not recognize the assignment expression? Do they not know what the result of such an expression is? Are they confused about user-defined conversion operators? Is `Foo` of class or enum type to begin with? No one knows...

Comment: @Stargateur, ok the *code* is strange then, not the question.

Comment: @Quentin  - Either way - why would you try to do two things at once

Comment: @EdHeal so that `f` is scoped inside the `if`. This is extremely useful for e.g. `if(auto p = some_weak_ptr.lock()) { /* use p */ }`. Also, C++17 will bring *if-with-initializer* so you can separate the condition from the scoped object.

Comment: @Quentin, so then why include an `if`?  Why not just a bare block?

Comment: I beg to differ - I think that doing one thing at a time in code makes life easier. You must bear inn mind what the other person might understand without the knowledge of the ins and outs of C+++

Comment: @JoelFan because the conversion to `bool` (or similar) decides whether you actually enter the block or not. See my example above: if the `weak_ptr` is expired, it evaluates to `false`, and you don't enter the block.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What is the if clause checking exactly? Can a constructor evaluate as NULL?

That line is equivalent to:

```
// Create a new scope
{
   // Create the object in the new scope
   Foo f = "something";

   // Use if
   if ( f )
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

That will work if there a user defined function that convert a `Foo` to a `bool`. Otherwise, it won't work. There is no direct relationship to NULL. However, if there is user defined conversion to any kind of pointer, then

```
if ( f ) { ... }
```

is the same as

```
if ( f != NULL ) { ... }
```

If you use C++11, that is also the same as

```
if ( f != nullptr ) { ... }
```

#### Example 1 (This does not work):

```
struct Foo
{
   Foo(char const*) {}
};

int main()
{
   Foo f = "something";

   // Does not work.
   // There is nothing to convert a Foo to a bool
   if ( f )
   {
      std::cout << "true\n";
   }
}
```

#### Example 2 (This does work):

```
struct Foo
{
   Foo(char const*) {}

   // A direct conversion function to bool
   operator bool () { return true; }
};

int main()
{
   Foo f = "something";
   if ( f )
   {
      std::cout << "true\n";
   }
}
```

#### Example 3 (This does work):

```
struct Foo
{
   Foo(char const*) {}

   // A direct conversion function to void*
   operator void* () { return this; }
};

int main()
{
   Foo f = "something";

   if ( f )
   {
      std::cout << "true\n";
   }

   // Same as above
   if ( f != NULL )
   {
      std::cout << "true\n";
   }

   // Same as above
   if ( f != nullptr )
   {
      std::cout << "true\n";
   }
}
```

Comment: It also requires that `Foo` have a copy/move assignment operator that accepts a `const char*` or convertible type

Comment: @Olipro, true. I am assuming the OP understands that part.

Comment: @RSahu, no I don't... I thought that a regular constructor would be called with = syntax.  I think the = syntax is equivalent to `Foo f("something");`

Comment: @JoelFan, if there is a constructor that takes a `char const*`, then that constructor will be called. If there ins't one, the compiler will try to use the best matching constructor that matches `char const*` as argument type.

Comment: @JoelFan, I wanted to use the answer to expand on the `if` clause, not get into the details of how `f` is constructed.

Comment: I think that could be a good idea to make a [mcve] that compile with this strange case.

Comment: Actually, there *is* a relationship to `NULL`: a conversion to a pointer type will work as well (and is the basis of the "safe bool idiom", also known as "why the hell is a `std::istream` convertible to `void*`").

Comment: @Olipro: "Assignment operator"? This code will not use *assignment operator*. It requres `Foo` to have a *conversion constructor* from `const char *` or from `const char [10]`.

Comment: @Stargateur, It definitely helps to have one or more [mcve]s.